# how to get notified when the window title bar is pressed/clicked

Tags: java, swing

I am working on an auto-dropdown suggestions window (like Google), using a JWindow (not a JPopupMenu). My dropdown JWindow is not focusable and not modal (the text field needs to keep the focus while the user types).

I would like to close the dropdown whenever the user presses the mouse anywhere outside the dropdown or if the app loses focus or is minimized or the escape key is pressed (basically like JPopupMenu behaves).

I have it working **except i cannot figure out how to get an event when the user presses the main frame title bar** (which causes the main frame to go in front of the dropdown).

I fear there is no event for this, as I am not receiving anything with this listener:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myTestListener, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

How is JPopupMenu achieving this behavior, anyway?

EDIT: added SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SSCCE
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton button = new JButton("open popup");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        openPopup(frame);
      }
    });

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static void openPopup(JFrame frame)
  {
    final JWindow popupWindow = new JWindow();
    popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
    popupWindow.setSize(400, 400);
    popupWindow.setLocation(frame.getX() + 200, frame.getY() + 200);
    ((JComponent) popupWindow.getContentPane()).setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.RED));
    popupWindow.setVisible(true);

    AWTEventListener awtEventListener = new AWTEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println(e.toString());

        if(e instanceof MouseEvent
            && ((MouseEvent) e).getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED //
            || e instanceof FocusEvent
            && ((FocusEvent) e).getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST //
            || e instanceof ComponentEvent
            && ((ComponentEvent) e).getID() == ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_MOVED
            && e.getSource() != popupWindow //
            || e instanceof ComponentEvent && ((ComponentEvent) e).getID() == ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED
            && e.getSource() != popupWindow//
            || e instanceof WindowEvent && ((WindowEvent) e).getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED //
            || e instanceof WindowEvent && ((WindowEvent) e).getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_ACTIVATED //
            || e instanceof WindowEvent && ((WindowEvent) e).getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_DEACTIVATED //
            || e instanceof WindowEvent && ((WindowEvent) e).getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_GAINED_FOCUS //
            || e instanceof WindowEvent && ((WindowEvent) e).getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS //
            || e instanceof KeyEvent && ((KeyEvent) e).getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE //
        )
        {
          popupWindow.setVisible(false);
          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(this);
        }
      }
    };

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(awtEventListener, 0xFFFFFFFF);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `WindowListener.windowActivated()`?

Comment: I believe my AWT event listener should have also gotten all window events, including windowActivated. But I'll try again... (after testing: no, I do get windowActivated events when I minimize and restore my main frame, but no just by clicking on the window title bar).

Comment: As I recall, it is impossible or at least very difficult. See for example http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6491619

Comment: JComboBox popups close when you click on the containing Window's native title bar or border, which apparently JPopupMenus do, too, so there is definitely a way to do this. I have asked a related question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810491/how-to-detect-if-user-clicks-on-window-title-bar-or-any-other-part-of-window-bor

Answer (score 1):

First, start by taking a look at the documentation for [`Toolkit#addAWTEventListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener(java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long))

> **Parameters:**
>  listener - the event listener.
>  eventMask -
>   the bitmask of event types to receive

The `eventMask` is a bitmask of the event id's you want to receive.  Okay, it's less then spectacular, but what it means is, you should be passing a or'ed list of event id's that you are interested in been notified about...

Now the question becomes, what events are we interested and how do we get the id's...

Well, [`AWTEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html) contains a list of event ids that work with `Toolkit`, [`AWTEvent.WINDOW_FOCUS_EVENT_MASK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html#WINDOW_FOCUS_EVENT_MASK) and possible even [`AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html#FOCUS_EVENT_MASK) might be useful.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myTestListener, 
        AWTEvent.WINDOW_FOCUS_EVENT_MASK | 
        AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
```

For example...

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFocus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFocus();
    }

    public TestFocus() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                    if (event instanceof WindowEvent) {
                        System.out.println("WindowEvent");
                        WindowEvent evt = (WindowEvent) event;
                        if (evt.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_GAINED_FOCUS) {
                            System.out.println("I got you babe");
                        } else if (evt.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS) {
                            System.out.println("Don't leave me!");
                        }
                    } else if (event instanceof FocusEvent) {
                        System.out.println("FocusEvent");
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.WINDOW_FOCUS_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

    }

}
```

These will tell you when a change in the focus state occurs, you would then need to check with the [`KeyboardFocusManager#getFocusOwner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getFocusOwner()) and/or [`KeyboardFocusManager#getGlobalFocusedWindow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getGlobalFocusedWindow()) to determine if your window still has focus or not.

Equally, you could just try using [`KeyboardFocusManager#addPropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#addPropertyChangeListener(java.beans.PropertyChangeListener)) and monitor the changes to the `KeyboardFocusManager`...

Comment: I was using Integer.MAX_VALUE as a lazy way to listen to all possible events. Unfortunately I am not receiving any notification at all when clicking on the window title bar.

Comment: I thought I am listening to every possible event there is, but when I click on the main frame title bar, I'm not getting any event at all. Also now I'm starting to think maybe I should have used 0xFFFFFFFF instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: The only likely events you will get a `WINDOW_LOST/GAIN_FOCUS` events, these are really, the only possible ones that would be triggered...Is the popup window focusable?

Comment: No the popup JWindow is not focusable.

Comment: Well, that could be a problem, if the popup window is not focusable, the parent window will never lose focus, and therefore never need to regain focus...

Comment: The Window that `JPopupMenu` is generated deep within the bowels of the API, you're not making the Window unfocusable, but the component itself...you could just use a `JPopupMenu` instead and save yourself some headaches ;)

Comment: Yes, JPopupMenu seems to be the only component that has the magic sauce :-(. I actually started with a JPopupMenu, only to hit other weird problems. I have always wondered if it is really impossible to duplicate JPopupMenu functionality with a JWindow. But: Even if you set the JWindow in the provided SSCCE to be focusable, there is no focus event when clicking the window title bar. Obviously the JWindow never received focus in the first place, but again - how does JPopupMenu do it? I would really like to find out :-)

Comment: Hm, you mean an undecorated JFrame does that not suffer from the same problem? I'll try it out immediately...

Comment: Shouldn't do.  I thought setting the `JWindow` to focusable would resolve it (don't recall trying), but obviously it didn't

Comment: Got my hopes up there for a while. I discarded the JFrame approach quickly because it creates a taskbar button. Moved to JDialog, which does get all of the window focus events, but grabs the focus from the textfield. When I use setFocusableWindowState(false) to avoid losing focus from the field, I am back to square one *sigh*.

Comment: What do you mean by *"but grabs the focus from the textfield"*?  The textfield in the parent frame or the popup?

Comment: The textfield in the parent frame for which I am trying to show a "suggestion dropdown" when the user types. Maybe I should adjust the SSCCE to reflect this.

Comment: I think the issue is you're focusing the title bar.  If focus changes to another field, then the popup should be closed, if the window focus (of the currently focus field) changes, it should be closed, but not sure about clicking the window title...

Comment: Just figured out that I should pass the owning frame to the JWindow constructor, which will keep the popup window in the front when clicking the owning frame title bar. Maybe now I can live with the fact that the popup is not closed. Anyway thanks a lot for your suggestions! I gave you an upvote for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If `windowActivated()` does not work for you, then as a last resort you can always set your JFrame as undecorated and create your own title bar.  It will not look like a native title bar any more, but you will have more control, including the ability to add a mouse listener.

```
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to my question but still an important detail: I forgot to pass the owning frame to the constructor of the popup JWindow. This will at least prevent the popup from being hidden behind the main frame, when the main frame title bar is clicked.