# How to detect if user clicks on window title bar or any other part of window border in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have implemented a pop-up numeric keypad using the Swing Popup class. I have a button associated with a JTextField that opens the numeric keypad when the user clicks on it, and then when/if the JTextField loses focus the Popup closes. It generally works well, except that occasionally I get artifacts that are "left over" from a Popup after it has been hidden. Sometimes the artifact is an image of the Components that were shown in the Popup, but more often it is a "black hole" of sorts that obscures anything else displayed in the same area of the screen in which the Popup had been, which can only be remedied by shutting down the application and the JVM.

The problem is difficult to reproduce, but it seems to manifest when the user manipulates the base Window while the Popup is open, such as by moving or resizing it. My thought is to simply hide the Popup when anything like that happens, which I can do with a combination of a WindowListener and a ComponentListener. However, I'd like to take it one step further and hide the Popup as soon as the user so much as clicks on the window title bar or another portion of its frame, even before they move, resize or iconify it. JComboBox popups in fact work this way. However, I have been unable to find any kind of mechanism by which I can be notified that a user has clicked on the window title bar. I've looked at the JComboBox and related code and can't figure out from that how it's working this magic, either. Is there any other kind of listener I could use to get this kind of notification?

Comment: *"if the JTextField loses focus the Popup closes."* That doesn't sound like something I as a user would appreciate. Let the user decide when he's done entering something and let him close the window.

Comment: The image artifacts can probably be fixed by repainting the frame. `jFrame.repaint()`. Are you using a focus listener for this? Using things like window listeners and component listeners seems like the wrong way to go about this. It sounds like what you actually want primarily is to listen to `focusLost` on the text field.

Comment: And if you are implementing custom focus behavior, you should read the focus specification which explains in great length how the focus system works and how to go about doing something like this correctly. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html

Comment: Radiodef, I do close the popup on a `focusLost` on the JTextField. The problem is, merely clicking on the window title bar does not cause a JTextField in the window to lose the focus.

Comment: 1. (based on your description) Focus is pretty asynchronous, by wrapping Focus into invokeLater will help you, for (JTextComponents and their XxxListeners) code compiled Java 6&7, 2. nothing else without (The problem is difficult to reproduce, but it seems...) an SSCCE / MCVE

Comment: you can debugging Focus events, to start with getOppositeComponent etc...

Comment: Simply relying on Focus events is not adequate, since as I noted in an earlier comment, merely clicking on a window's title bar does not effect a focus change. JComboBox is detecting such a thing by some other mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have implemented a pop-up numeric keypad using the Swing Popup class.

Well post your code demonstrating the implementation and problem when you post a question.

I don't know exactly what you are doing but you might be able to use a `JPopupMenu`. This will close when you click on the frame title bar with no FocusListener or any additional logic.

Comment: I know from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136875/how-to-get-notified-when-the-window-title-bar-is-pressed-clicked#comment74663116_27136875) that JPopupMenu also implements the same magic sauce that JComboBox does. However, the contents of the popup needs to be a bunch of JButtons, not menu options as JPopupMenu implements. I will post the code I use to create my popup later today, in case there is something about the way I create it that I could do differently.

Comment: @KevinRahe `However, the contents of the popup needs to be a bunch of JButtons` - did you try it?

Comment: I didn't think about using a JPopupMenu as merely a blank Container rather than a menu. It actually does what I need. I looked at its code to see what kind of magic sauce it might be using, especially with the Popup, which it uses internally. It's invoking private PopupFactory methods, which of course I can't do from my code, so it may be that using a JPopupMenu is the only way to get the behavior I seek.

Comment: In NetBeans you can't add general controls to a JPopupMenu. I was able to work around this by creating my numeric keypad panel as a JPanel, then merely changing the code to extend JPopupMenu rather than JPanel after the GUI development was complete. In order to do any further editing of the GUI, I would probably have to temporarily change it back to extending JPanel, but this is a minor inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

will be deleted, just code for testing,

```
private boolean _myWindowFocusLost = false;
```

.

```
        _xxXxx.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {//Invoked when a component gains the keyboard focus.
                if (e.getOppositeComponent() != null) {
                    if (e.getOppositeComponent() instanceof JComponent) {
                        JComponent opposite = (JComponent) e.getOppositeComponent();
                        if ((opposite.getTopLevelAncestor() != _myPopupWindow) && (!_myWindowFocusLost)) {
                            _myWindowFocusLost = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```